# How to redirect from http to https at Masterhost shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net, .htaccess, redirect, https

How to redirect from http to https for linux and windows for Masterhost shared hosting.

For that particular case checking if connection is secure fails, aswell as checking X-Forwarded-Proto.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !443
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

global.asax:

```
    if (Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Port"] == "443") //masterhost hosting only
    { 
        //nothing, its secure

    }
    else
    {
        //force https
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);            
    }
```